# How could I retrieve text from Firebase, using ExpandableTextView lib?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to add just one text per item, but I need to **retrieve different texts from firebase** and show it in the **ExpandableTextView**. How could I do it? Do you guys know something that can help me please?

I'm using this lib here: https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

**This is my Target Java class:**

```
private String mPost_key = null;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private ImageView mPostImage;
    private TextView mPostTitle;
    private TextView mPostDesc;

ExpandableTextView expandableTextView;
    String longText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setSubtitle(R.string.Post_Name_Toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        expandableTextView = (ExpandableTextView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
        expandableTextView.setText(longText);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Videos");

        mPost_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("post_id");

        mPostImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PostImage);
        mPostDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostDesc);
        mPostTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostTitle);

        //Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, post_key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mDatabase.child(mPost_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String post_title = (String) dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
                String post_desc = (String) dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue();
                String post_image = (String) dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue();

                mPostTitle.setText(post_title);
                mPostDesc.setText(post_desc);

                Picasso.with(PostActivity.this).load(post_image).into(mPostImage);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```